# Correct practice using 'using' in C++ templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, using

I have a small class that uses several STL lists internally

```
template<class T>
class MC_base {

  using OBJ_LIST  = std::list<T>;
  using OBJ_VAL   = typename OBJ_LIST::value_type;
  using OBJ_ITR   = typename OBJ_LIST::iterator;
  using OBJ_CITR  = typename OBJ_LIST::const_iterator;

  OBJ_LIST A,B,C;
  ...
};
```

With the `using` statements, if I write an iterator inside the class definition, it looks nice and clean:

```
OBJ_ITR begin() { return A.begin(); };
OBJ_ITR end()   { return A.end();   };
OBJ_CITR begin() const { return A.begin(); };
OBJ_CITR end()   const { return A.end();   };
```

Writing new functions, again inside the class definition, is easy since I can simply use the names `OBJ_XXXX` names when needed. Furthermore, if I decide to change the container type (to say `std::vector`) at some point later, I only have to change one line and as long as my new container supports all the same actions everything should be seamless.

This is problematic however when I want to define a new class function outside of the class definition

```
template<class T>
OBJ_ITR MC_base<T>::foo(OBJ_ITR x) { ... }
```

I'm not sure how to "bring out" the using statements so they work correctly with the templates and not to define them for *every function* which would be overly verbose. Also, I don't want to pollute the namespace with my using statements.

Is there a proper way to use `using` with templates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a trailing return type. The type is looked up in the scope of the class, as with the parameter types, so nested types don't need qualification.

```
template<class T>
auto MC_base<T>::foo(OBJ_ITR x) -> OBJ_ITR { ... }
```

Comment: +1 that's great. I thought also about the solution in Ben's answer, but this is often much more compact. It's all in _gx's comment already, though ...

Comment: (Since I commented there) Live example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18595111/correct-practice-using-using-in-c-templates/18595161#comment27367228_18595161)

Comment: @gx_: Sorry, I didn't notice that you'd already answered in a comment; I just read the other answer before adding mine.

Comment: Question: Can trailing return type be used on the definition if it wasn't used in the declaration?

Comment: @BenVoigt: I didn't think of that. It worked when I tried it, and it seems silly to disallow it, but of course that doesn't necessarily mean it's allowed.

Comment: Hmm, I found this rule: "Redeclarations or specializations of a function or function template with a declared return type that uses a
placeholder type shall also use that placeholder, not a deduced type." in section 7.1.6.4  But "If the function declarator includes a trailing-return-type, that specifies the declared return type of the function."

Comment: @BenVoigt These quotes seem to be from the C++14 (sorry, C++1y) draft (N3690) where "placeholder type" refers to `auto` _without_ a trailing return type, that didn't exist in the C++11 standard (really N3337). My understanding is that in C++11 the "`auto` + trailing-return-type" form is just a syntactic convenience.

Comment: @gx_: Yes, they are.  I should go back and check the C++11 wording.  Still, in C++1y, placeholder types clearly include this case: "The `auto` and `decltype(auto)` *type-specifiers* designate a placeholder type that will be replaced later, either by deduction from an initializer or by explicit specification with a *trailing-return-type*."

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for the correction _(that was the very first paragraph... I must be tired)_. Maybe the rule you found relates to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18519603) and [its "mirror"](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#{%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A{%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue}%2C%22compilers%22%3A[{%22source%22%3A%22auto%20f%28%29%3B\nint%20f%28%29%20{%20return%200%3B%20}\n\nint%20main%28%29\n{\n%20%20return%20f%28%29%3B\n}%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22%2Fusr%2Fbin%2Fg%2B%2B-4.8%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-std%3Dc%2B%2B1y%20-Wall%20-pedantic%22}]})

Comment: @gx_: Yeah, that looks relevant.

Answer (score 5):

Outside the class, you need to qualify the names.  You additionally need to use the `typename` keyword to promise the compiler that those names are types in *every* specialization.

```
template<class T>
typename MC_base<T>::OBJ_ITR MC_base<T>::foo( typename MC_base<T>::OBJ_ITR x ) { ... }
```

---

9.3p2 requires that

> A member function deﬁnition that appears outside of the class definition shall appear
>   in a namespace scope enclosing the class definition.

Which prevents using a more nested scope for the definition where these names would be present.  Not to mention the problem that those names depend on the template parameter.

---

The best solution is probably to write those functions inline.  These are members of a template class, so they have to be included in the header file anyway.

Comment: It now exists a syntax to delay the function return type at a time the scope is the class, it looks like `template <T> auto Myclass::Func( arg) -> NestedClassTypeFromMyClass { //...`

Comment: @Hooked @BenVoigt The whole typename qualified thing is not needed for the parameter type since we're already in the class' scope. And using the trailing return type gives the even shorter: `template<class T>
auto MC_base<T>::foo(OBJ_ITR x) -> OBJ_ITR { ... }`. http://ideone.com/j7embB

Comment: @gx_ That's a nice way to do it with `auto`. Can you put that in its own answer for posterities sake?

Comment: @Hooked I actually expected that Ben Voigt would add this alternative to his answer but it seems that Mike Seymour posted it as his own answer before I even saw your reply.

Comment: @gx_ in my world, we call that getting scooped. Either way, your answer via Mike S. seems to be more C++11 so I'm going to change the acceptance to his. The information in this answer however was extremely valuable in understanding the problem Ben!