# Varying function return type C++

Tags: c++, c++14

So with the new `auto` return type deductions in C++14, is there a way to create functions that have varying return types?

For example:

```
auto replaceStr(string base, string search, string replace) {
  size_t found = base.find(search);
  if (found == string::npos) {
    return false; //Return this is replace is not found
  }
  else {
    base.replace(found, (found+search.length()), replace);
    return base; //Return this after the replacement
  }
}
```

This doesn't work, I know. So is there a way to get it to work?

**EDIT:** Most people in the comments have been telling me this impossible since the compiler doesn't know what return type the function is at compilation. So perhaps we can have the function have a default return type with optional return types?

Comment: nope.  no way to make it work.  the closest that you can do is to make a base class and declare the function to return that class.

Comment: Doing this would be a massive change for C++. The return type of the function wouldn't be known at compile-time. You should consider `std::optional<std::string>` or something more explicit for the information your return value carries. Personally, returning the parameter seems odd if you're going to return whether the replacement did anything.

Comment: If you could do this, what would you store the result in? ;)

Comment: is there a language that lets you return different types?

Comment: @thang, Javascript, PHP, Python, most other languages with dynamic typing I'm guessing.

Comment: Exactly, only with dynamic typing does that sort of thing make sense.

Comment: @chris, They're not really.  For those languages, all the types have the same base class.  We can do the the same in C++ by having a base Object class.  We can then declare Boolean and String to be inherited from Object.  In this case, you can have in Object in place of auto.  This would have the same functionality as what you get in javascript, java, etc.

Comment: Several of them. Python, PHP, JavaScript, Swift, etc. Objective-C also allows this through its `id` mechanism. They're called "Weakly typed" languages for this reason.

Comment: @thang You can return lots of things (e.g. integers) from a Python function that aren't a subclass of `object`.

Comment: @Thang there is, but they're mostly interpreters like Lua and Python

Comment: That's because in those interpretive languages, you can have a variable without at type.  That's not the case in C++.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone, you're right.  I guess internally they tag the type.

Comment: One way to build something like this into C++ is to have a struct with type as a field.  This is how COM builds variable typing on top of c.

Comment: @Brian,haha,still use wonderful auto.

Comment: @thang why reinvent RTTI and `dynamic_cast`? All you need to return multiple types from a function is some kind of base class or wrapper class.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone, yea that works too.  That's the base class idea from my previous comment.  I guess the overhead may be a little larger, depending on the details.

Comment: Actually, for this particular example, returning something like shared_ptr<string> makes sense.  it's null if not found.  otherwise, it's base.

Comment: You should use something like [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html), or it's `std` equivalent if it's available on your platform.

Answer (score 5):

**C++ is a statically typed language**: There is no way to return a variable type that is not known during compile time.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1517582/2034041) about statically- and dynamically-typed language differences, which are also known as [weak or strong typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing).

About C++14 `auto` return type, see [When should I use C++14 automatic return type deduction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15737223/2034041)

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out, the compiler needs to know the function return type at compile time.

For your particular example you could return a `std::pair<bool, string>`. In the case where no substitution is made, the `second` member of the pair is ignored.

```
auto res = replaceStr(base, search, replace);
if (res.first) {
    auto newBase = res.second;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this doesn't answer your question directly, a common way to do this would be to pass a reference:

```
bool replaceStr(string &base, string search, string replace) {
    size_t found = base.find(search);
    if (found == string::npos) {
        return false; //Return this is replace is not found
    }
    base.replace(found, (found+search.length()), replace);
    return true;
}
```

You would then use it like:

```
if (replaceStr(base,search,replace)) {
    // it was replaced, use the modified base.
}
else {
    // it wasn't replaced
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Most people in the comments have been telling me this impossible since
>   the compiler doesn't know what return type the function is at
>   compilation.

The compiler **does** know the type. If the compiler is unable to deduce the type, the program is ill-formed and won't compile. `auto` doesn't mean weakly-typed, it represents a placeholder type which can be deduced using template argument deduction.

Comment: You misinterpreted that sentence.  "doesn't know" should be interpreted as "wouldn't be able to deduce".  It's implied.  Otherwise the sentence would be trivially false (Gricean :p)

Comment: @thang Actually, the OP just misquoted chris, who said "the compiler **wouldn't** know", appertaining to C++ if it was weakly-typed.

Comment: probably.  i don't know.  i always give people the benefit of the doubt.  if a statement is obviously false, it probably means the author meant something else.

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't directly support variable return types but it's certainly possible to implement. Here's an example of variable return types with the return type selected at compile time in one case and at runtime in the other case.

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

// dynamically varying return type
class AnyBase
{
public:
    virtual ~AnyBase() {};
    const std::string as_string() const
    {
        return this->as_string_v();
    }


private:
    virtual const std::string as_string_v() const = 0;
};
typedef AnyBase Any;

template<typename T>
class AnyDerived : public AnyBase
{
    T* obj_ptr_;

public:
    template<typename... Args>
    AnyDerived(Args&&... args)
    {
        obj_ptr_ = new T(std::forward<Args...>(args...));
    }

    ~AnyDerived()
    {
        delete obj_ptr_;
    }

private:
    const std::string as_string_v() const;
    const char* type_string_v() const;
};

template<class T>
const std::string AnyDerived<T>::as_string_v() const
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << *obj_ptr_;
    return oss.str();
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Any& a)
{
    os << a.as_string();
    return os;
}


std::unique_ptr<Any> foo(bool as_char)
{
    if (as_char)
        return std::unique_ptr<Any>{new AnyDerived<char>('1')};
    else
        return std::unique_ptr<Any>{new AnyDerived<int>(1)};
}


// statically varying return type
template<typename T>
T bar()
{
    return 1;
}

template<>
char bar<char>()
{
    return '1';
}


int main()
{
    bool as_char;
    as_char = true;
    const auto a1 = foo(as_char);
    as_char = false;
    const auto a2 = foo(as_char);
    const auto a3 = bar<int>();
    const auto a4 = bar<char>();

    std::cout << "*a1: " << *a1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*a2: " << *a2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << " a3: " <<  a3 << std::endl;
    std::cout << " a4: " <<  a4 << std::endl;
}
```

`a1` wraps a pointer to `char`, `a2` wraps a pointer to `int`, `a3` is an `int` and `a4` is a `char`. As you can see in `main()`, it can be made fairly transparent.

output:

```
*a1: 1
*a2: 1
 a3: 1
 a4: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I'd just throw on error.

```
string replaceStr(string base, string search, string replace) {
  size_t found = base.find(search);
  if (found == string::npos) {
    throw MyException(); 
  }
  else {
    base.replace(found, (found+search.length()), replace);
    return base; //Return this after the replacement
  }
}
```

But if you want to create a factory-like function that returns anything you can:

- use polymorphism and return a pointer to the base
- cast anything you want to `std::shared_ptr<void>`.
- use boost::any

Comment: I did this originally, but I wanted to cut down on the use of try catch statements

Answer (score 0):

Your function can return `void*`, which can point to anything. This approach, however, may get you in trouble with managing memory if you are not careful.