# C++: Deriving a function return type using decltype

Tags: c++11, c++14, return-type, decltype

The following is a (over-)simplified excerpt of a real C++14 application. For reasons of maintainability I did not want to specify the return type of `foo()` explicitly. I am aware that C++14 can deduce the return type of functions `auto`matically. But the real application required the return type inside the function. So I needed it at hand.

The following code snippet compiles (g++ 4.9.2) fine:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//auto foo (std::wstring &s) -> std::remove_reference <decltype (s)>::size_type
auto foo (std::wstring &s) -> decltype (s.length ())
    {
    return s.length ();
    }

int main ()
    {
    std::wstring s {L"hello world"};
    std::cout << foo (s) << "\n";
    return 0;
    }
```

But if I use the "commented-out" version of the function declaration I get the following diagnostics:

```
foo.cpp:5:69: error: ‘size_type’ in ‘struct std::remove_reference<std::basic_string<wchar_t>&>’ does not name a type
auto foo (std::wstring &s) -> std::remove_reference <decltype (s)>::size_type
                                                                    ^
```

What's wrong? Isn't `std::wstring::size_type` a type?
Doesn't `std::remove_reference` convert `std::basic_string<wchar_t>&` into a plain `std::wstring`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::remove_reference` does not have a `size_type` member, `std::wstring` has. You can access `std::wstring` with `std::remove_reference<decltype(s)>::type`. Therefore, what you really need for your return type is:

```
std::remove_reference <decltype (s)>::type::size_type
```

Since you are using C++14, you can use `std::remove_reference_t` instead, which is an alias template shortcut introduced for readability:

```
std::remove_reference_t <decltype (s)>::size_type
```

**EDIT:** As noted by @Cassio in the comments, since you are using C++14, you may as well let the function deduce the return type with `auto` which will automatically strip the reference:

```
auto foo (std::wstring &s)
    {
    return s.length ();
    }
```

That said, you should really think about [when you really want to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15737223/1364752). Many people prefere to have an explicit return type when it makes sense.

Comment: Suggestion to improve your answer: since it's C++14, we can use function return type deduction and simply write `auto foo (std::wstring& s) {     return s.length (); }`.

Comment: As already stated in my initial post the example is oversimplified. In fact (again, as stated) I require the type **inside** the function. Therefore return type deduction of C++14 is of no help here.