# Idiomatic way to calculate template parameter depending on other parameters

Tags: c++, c++14

I am looking for an idiomatic way to optimize this template I wrote.

My main concern is how to correctly define the template parameter `n` and using it as a return parameter while the user must not overwrite it.

I am also open for other suggestions on how to write this template in an idiomatic C++14 way.

```
template<
  typename InType=uint32_t,
  typename OutType=float,
  unsigned long bits=8,
  unsigned long n=(sizeof(InType) * 8) / bits
>
std::array<OutType,n> hash_to_color(InType in) noexcept {    
  InType mask = ~0;
  mask = mask << bits;
  mask = ~mask;
  std::array<OutType,n> out;
  auto out_max = static_cast<OutType>((1 << bits) - 1);
  for (auto i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    auto selected = (in >> (i * bits)) & mask;
    out[i] = static_cast<OutType>(selected) / out_max;
  }
  return out;
}
```

Comment: If you want to ensure that the user doesn't override it, perhaps you can just `static_assert` that it's the correct value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the `n` template parameter, you can avoid it by using `auto` as the return type in C++14. Here's a simpler example of the principle:

```
template<int N>
auto f()
{
    constexpr int bar = N * 3;   
    std::array<int, bar> foo;
    return foo;
}
```

Naturally the calculation of the array template parameter must be a constant expression.

Another option (compatible with C++11) is trailing-return-type:

```
template<int N>
auto f() -> std::array<int, N * 3>
{
```

This is a wee bit more verbose than taking advantage of C++14's allowing of return type deduction from the `return` statement.

Note: `~0` in your code is wrong because `0` is an `int`, it should be `~(InType)0`. Also `(1 << bits) - 1` has potential overflow issues.

Comment: Thank you. That's helpful. I removed a few `static_assert` in the question code which ensure that bits don't overflow by `static_assert(bits < sizeof(OutType) * 8)`

Answer (score 2):

I think M.M.'s answer is excellent, and, in your case, I'd definitely use one of the two alternatives suggested there.

Suppose you later encounter a situation where the logic is, given *n*, use not *3 n*, but something more complicated, e.g., *n<sup>2</sup> + 3 n + 1*. Alternatively, maybe the logic is not very complicated, but it is subject to change.

- The first option - using automatically deduced `auto`, is pithy, but [the omission sometimes makes the declaration less clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737223/when-should-i-use-c14-automatic-return-type-deduction).
- The second option - trailing return type - violates [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) to some extent.

(Just to clarify again, I don't think that these are significant problems in the context of your question or M.M.'s answer.)

So, a third option would be to factor out the logic to a `constexpr` function:

```
#include <array>

constexpr int arr_size(int n) { return n * n + 3 * n + 1; }
```

Since it's `constexpr`, it can be used to instantiate the template:

```
template<int N>
std::array<int, arr_size(N)> f() {
    return  std::array<int, arr_size(N)>();
}
```

Note that now the function has an explicit return type, but the logic of `arr_size` appears only once.

You could use this as usual:

```
int main() {
    auto a = f<10>();
    a[0] = 3;
}
```