# Advantage of using trailing return type in C++11 functions

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, trailing-return-type

What is the advantage of specifying a trailing return type in C++11, as opposed to a normal return type? Look at `foo1` vs `foo2` here:

```
int foo1() {
    return 1;    
}

auto foo2() -> int {
    return 1;    
}

int main() {
    foo1();
    foo2();
}
```

Comment: Very similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737223/when-should-i-use-c14-automatic-return-type-deduction

Comment: You'll learn the usefulness of auto when you get to working with template functions where the return type varies.

Comment: @rustyx I am asking about C++11 not C++14, there is a difference

Comment: What's the difference do you think?

Comment: @rustyx, in C++14 I can use ```auto foo2()``` and return type is deducted from return value, in C++11 I do not think it isn possible.

Comment: @Barry, your edits may make this question less Googlable because I and others would have Googled something about "auto in return type", not "trailing return type", because we didn't know what "trailing return type" was. Consider putting back the original wording but placing your corrections in parenthesis after the original wording to add clarity that your wording is more correct, while leaving the original wording which is more searchable to the average person wondering about this.

Comment: @GabrielStaples You could also edit the question. You don't have to ask me to.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In this example, they mean the exact same thing.

However, there are a few advantages to using the trailing return type form consistently (Phil Nash calls these ["East End Functions"](https://levelofindirection.com/blog/east-end-functions.html), since the return type is on the east end).

1. Using parameters. Obviously when using parameters to determine the return type, you *must* use a trailing return type.

   ```
    template <typename T>
    auto print(T const& t) -> decltype(std::cout << t) { return std::cout << t; }
   ```
2. Name lookup. In a trailing return type, name lookup includes the class scope for member function definitions. This means you don't have to retype the class if you want to return a nested class:

   ```
    Type C::foo() { ... }         // error: don't know what Type is
    C::Type C::foo() { ... }      // ok

    auto C::foo() -> Type { ... } // ok
   ```
3. Likewise, for defining member functions where the class name for some reason must be disambiguated to be in the global namespace and the return type is a class:

   ```
    D ::C::foo() { ... }         // error, parsed as D::C::foo() { ... }

    auto ::C::foo() -> D { ... } // ok
   ```
4. If you are returning types like pointers to functions or pointers to arrays, it's actually possible to both write and understand the declaration using the trailing type syntax - whereas getting the syntax correct in the "normal" syntax is a challenge in its own right, understanding it even more so. These are both declarations of a function that takes no parameters and returns a pointer to function that takes an `int` and returns an `int`:

   ```cpp
   int (*get_function())(int);             // traditional
   auto get_function() -> int (*)(int);    // trailing return type
   ```
5. A more reasonable ordering of information. Let's say you want to write a function `to_string` that takes an `int` and returns an `string`. That's a pretty sensible way of phrasing that. Function name, parameters, return type. You wouldn't say you want to write a `string`-returning function named `to_string` that takes an `int`. That's an awkward order of information. The name is the most important, followed by the parameters, followed by the return type. The trailing-return-type form allows you to order these pieces of information better.

There are cases where trailing-return-type is mandatory, there are cases where it is helpful, and there are cases where it does the same thing. There are not cases where it is worse for reasons other than simply character count.

Plus, mathemtically we're used to thinking of functions as `A -> B` and not so much `B(A)`, and so `auto(*)(A) -> B` as a function pointer taking an `A` and returning a `B` is a little closer to that view than `B(*)(A)`.

---

On the other hand, writing `auto main() -> int` looks ridiculous.

But honestly, that's mostly because of unfamiliarity. There's nothing inherently ridiculous about it. If anything, it's a bit unfortunate that the language uses `auto` here as a way to declare a function - not because it's too long (i.e. some other languages use `fun` or even `fn`) - but because it's not really distinct from other uses of `auto`. If it were `func` instead, I think it would have been better (although it would not make any sense to change now).

---

Ultimately, this is purely opinion based. Just write code that works.

Comment: One aesthetic reason for using `auto` as a return type is that for declarations it aligns function and method names nicely. I found it somewhat useful in practice when reading newer codes.

Comment: That is only applicable when your functions are not declared virtual or static.

Comment: @jmk it lines up if you add `static`, `virtual` and `[[attributes]]` on the previous line.