# Can we have a function with multiple return types? (in C++11 and above)

Tags: c++, function, c++11, templates, return-type

I am trying to write a  generic function which takes input as `uint8`, `uint16`, `uint32`, `uint64`, .... and return the maximum value with the datatype of largest element?

For example:

```
template < typename T, typename X>
auto Max_Number(T valueA, X valueB)
{
    if (valueA > valueB)
        return valueA;
    else
        return valueB;
}
```

P.S: this example assumes the largest element is of the largest datatype.

Comment: take a look at `std::variant` That's probably the closest since C++ is strongly typed

Comment: There might be some template wizards that could suggest something, but I'm fairly certain that the return type must be fixed

Comment: Have you tried to use plain [`std::max`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max)? Remember that integer types can safely be [implicitly converted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) to a larger type.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yep, that should work given his example's statement that the largest arg magnitude is also the largest datatype applies in all other cases.

Comment: Are the arguments always unsigned? It's not clear because of that "...". If they are, I would use simply `uintmax_t Max_Number(uintmax_t a, uintmax_t b) ...`.

Comment: @doug Strongly *and statically* typed; it's especially the second one which is relevant here.

Comment: Supose you have managed to write such a function. What would you do with the result? Can you show a use case?

Answer (score 27):

The return type must be determined at compile-time. You might use [`std::common_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) (since C++11):

> For arithmetic types not subject to promotion, the common type may be viewed as the type of the (possibly mixed-mode) arithmetic expression such as `T0() + T1() + ... + Tn()`.

```
template < typename T, typename X>
typename std::common_type<T, X>::type Max_Number ( T valueA, X valueB ) {
    ...
}
```

Or use [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) (since C++11) to declare the return type as the big one (whose `sizeof` is greater).

```
template < typename T, typename X>
typename std::conditional<sizeof(T) >= sizeof(X), T, X>::type Max_Number ( T valueA, X valueB ) {
    ...
}
```

Note that for this case, if `T` and `X` have the same size, `T` will always be used as the return type. If you want to control it more precisely, you can use some traits to specify the exact type.

Comment: The latter solution has the potential downside of not being commutative when T and X have the same size, e.g. on my system `Max_Number(1L, 2.0)` returns a long int and  `Max_Number(2.0, 1L)` returns a double. (Also, the `std::conditional_t` helper is only available in C++14.)

Answer (score 13):

Here is an example solution with [`std:: variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

```
template < typename T, typename X> 
std::variant<T, X>  Max_Number ( T valueA, X valueB )
{
    std::variant<T, X> res;
    if ( valueA > valueB ) 
       res = valueA; 
    else 
       res = valueB; 
    return res;
}
```

Comment: While this is correct, `std::variant` might be a overkill for the certain case, as other elegent solutions are available purely using C++11.

Comment: @Const all other solutions determine the type at compile time, which means that the resulting type depends only on the types of the parameters and not their values. In this solution the active return type is the type of the variable with the max value. So it's really apples and oranges and serve different situations. If you want the type to be the type of the max value, then this is the best solution.

Answer (score 11):

The *[Trailing return](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function)* with a *[conditional operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator)* is another way to go, which is available since [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11).

**([See online live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wXnJzPDb5kQy4ty7))**

```
template <typename T, typename X>
constexpr auto Max_Number(T valueA, X valueB)-> decltype(valueA > valueB ? valueA : valueB)
{
    return valueA > valueB ? valueA : valueB;
}
```

---

See some advantages of using trailing return type here: [Advantage of using trailing return type in C++11 functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52103775/advantage-of-using-trailing-return-type-in-c11-functions)

Comment: instead of the ? expression you could use valueA + valueB