# Choosing between different function declaration styles in C++: auto vs. traditional return type syntax

Tags: c++, auto, return-type-deduction

There are two distinct styles for declaring functions, each employing a different approach to specifying the return type. The first adheres to the traditional syntax:

```
bool getMode() const;
```

On the other hand, the second leverages the auto keyword and the arrow syntax for the return type:

```
auto getMode() const -> bool;
```

My primary question is whether there are any substantial reasons to prefer one style over the other. I understand that readability is often subjective, but are there any specific scenarios, best practices, or performance considerations that could guide the choice between these two styles?

Comment: I'm sorry but this is very personal and subjective. And for your simple case they are exactly the same.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No it's not personal, i just wonder is there good reason to prefer one way to another. If the choice depends on something complex, feel free to show.

Comment: Use whatever you prefer - in most cases it doesn't matter.

Comment: The lead developer on my team prefers using leading `auto` with trailing returns for functions and methods, because they sort nicely & easily.  (But still uses leading `void` for procedures, and leading `bool` for predicates.)

Comment: "[I] just wonder is there good reason to prefer one way to another." No, there's not. Other than personal preferences. There are cases where you *must* use trailing return type, which makes some people use it everywhere. But other people (myself included) only use trailing return type when needed and leading return type otherwise (which usually is the vast majority of cases anyway).

Comment: It's misleading to say it's only personal preference but you nailed the tradeoffs... Trailing return is newer and has strictly more power (where you must use it or would prefer it), so you can choose internal consistency or consistency with a lot of older code. And the best choice of guideline will be contextual.

Comment: [Advantage of using trailing return type in C++11 functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52103775/advantage-of-using-trailing-return-type-in-c11-functions)

Comment: There are no performance difference at all. You are even allowed to declare a function in one style, and then implement it using the other. No problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one semantic difference between the two, and it occurs when implementing a class method outside of the class. Suppose we have a class that defines a `typedef` and an instance method.

```
class Example {
  using my_type_t = int;
  my_type_t foobar();
};
```

Now we go to our `.cpp` file to implement this method. If we use trailing return type syntax, then everything just works.

```
auto Example::foobar() -> my_type_t {
  ...
}
```

However, if we put the type in front, then we have to prefix it with `Example::`

```
Example::my_type_t Example::foobar() {
  ...
}
```

This is simply because of the compiler's parse order. The compiler only "figures out" that we're inside of the class `Example` once it sees `Example::foobar`. If the return type is trailing, then it occurs after the qualified name of the method, so we know the scope. If the return type occurs *before* we see that name, then the return type is evaluated in the surrounding scope and has to be fully qualified.

This gets even messier with template classes. Compare

```
// Trailing syntax
template <typename T>
auto Example<T>::foobar() -> my_type_t {
  ...
}

// Prefix syntax
template <typename T>
typename Example<T>::my_type_t Example<T>::foobar() {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Ok seems reasonable, what about in case of namespace clashing ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What sort of clashing are you worried about?

Comment: I already got it answered, nevermind, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It seems both existing answers are missing one important case: When the return-type must be deduced, for example as a result of an expression.

The typical example is:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
auto add(A a, B b) -> decltype(a + b)
{
    // ...
}
```

Depending on the version of C++ you're using, and the complexity of the function, you must use trailing return type for this case.

Other than that, it could simplify some things as shown in the other answers. But beyond that it's still a personal and subjective choice.

Answer (score 0):

The second option can sometimes be considered more preferable, it allows to implement shorter a class member function that return a type defined in a class scope. But this is not always true, depends on an outer class name.

```
#include <iostream>

class Outer {
 public:
  class Inner {};
  Inner m();
  Inner n();
};

auto Outer::m() -> Inner {  // The name scope Outer:: is known and can be omitted
  return {};
}
// vs
Outer::Inner Outer::n() {  // Outer is a short name and the entire definition is shorter
  return {};
}
```